# Troubles with opening a large data set and instantiating the data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am attempting to read from a text file of GIS data in Java, instantiate each row of data, and then sort, search and insert data into it. I keep getting issues saying "at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)" and have been unable to fix this. I was also wondering if there were suggestions for different methods to do this.

I have tried using a data class, where I set all the variables I need to access, created getters and setters and an override. I then created a new array of the data, and used `if(input.hasNext())`, where I set each variable, and then create a new instance of the GISData.

```
public class GISRunner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Toby\\Desktop\\GIS.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.useDelimiter("||\n");

        GISData[] datas = new GISData[0];
        if(input.hasNext()) {
            int featureId = input.nextInt();
            String featureName = input.next();
            String featureClass = input.next();
            String stateCode = input.next();
            int stateId = input.nextInt();
            String countyName = input.next();
            int countyId = input.nextInt();
            String primaryLatitudeDMS = input.next();
            String primaryLongitudeDMS = input.next();
            double primaryLatitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(input.next().substring(1));
            double primaryLongitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(input.next().substring(1));
            String sourceLatitudeDMS = input.next();
            String sourceLongitudeDMS = input.next();
            double sourceLatitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(input.next().substring(1));
            double sourceLongitudeDecimal = Double.valueOf(input.next().substring(1));
            int elevationMeters = input.nextInt();
            int elevationFeet = input.nextInt();
            String mapName = input.next();

            GISData newGISData = new GISData(featureId, featureName, featureClass, stateCode,
                    stateId, countyName, countyId, primaryLatitudeDMS, primaryLongitudeDMS, 
                    primaryLatitudeDecimal, primaryLongitudeDecimal, sourceLatitudeDMS, 
                    sourceLongitudeDMS, sourceLatitudeDecimal, sourceLongitudeDecimal, elevationMeters, 
                    elevationFeet, mapName);
            datas = addGISData(datas, newGISData);
        }
        for (GISData data : datas) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }

    public static GISData[] addGISData(GISData[] datas, GISData dataToAdd) {
        GISData[] newGISData = new GISData[datas.length + 1 ];
        System.arraycopy(datas, 0, newGISData, 0, datas.length);
        newGISData[newGISData.length - 1 ] = dataToAdd;

        return newGISData;
    }

}


public class GISData implements Comparable<GISData> {
    public static enum SortByType {CountyName,
                                    FeatureName,
                                    PrimaryLatitude,
                                    PrimaryLongitude,
                                    SourceLatitude,
                                    SourceLongitude,
                                    ElevationFeet};

    private int featureId;
    private String featureName;
    private String featureClass;
    private String stateCode;
    private int stateId;
    private String countyName;
    private int countyId;
    private String primaryLatitudeDMS;
    private String primaryLongitudeDMS;
    private double primaryLatitudeDecimal;
    private double primaryLongitudeDecimal;
    private String sourceLatitudeDMS;
    private String sourceLongitudeDMS;
    private double sourceLatitudeDecimal;
    private double sourceLongitudeDecimal;
    private int elevationMeters;
    private int elevationFeet;
    private String mapName;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private SortByType[] sortBy;


    public GISData(int featureId2, String featureName2, String featureClass2, String stateCode2, int stateId2,
            String countyName2, int countyId2, String primaryLatitudeDMS2, String primaryLongitudeDMS2,
            double primaryLatitudeDecimal2, double primaryLongitudeDecimal2, String sourceLatitudeDMS2, String sourceLongitudeDMS2, double sourceLatitudeDecimal2,
            double sourceLongitudeDecimal2, int elevationMeters2, int elevationFeet2, String mapName2) {
        featureId = featureId2;
        featureName2 = featureName;
        featureClass2 = featureClass;
        stateCode2 = stateCode;
        stateId2 = stateId;
        countyName2 = countyName;
        countyId2 = countyId;
        primaryLatitudeDMS2 = primaryLatitudeDMS;
        primaryLongitudeDMS2 = primaryLongitudeDMS;
        primaryLatitudeDecimal2 = primaryLatitudeDecimal;
        primaryLongitudeDecimal2 = primaryLongitudeDecimal;
        sourceLatitudeDMS2 = sourceLatitudeDMS;
        sourceLongitudeDMS2 = sourceLongitudeDMS;
        sourceLatitudeDecimal2 = sourceLatitudeDecimal;
        sourceLongitudeDecimal2 = sourceLongitudeDecimal;
        elevationMeters2 = elevationMeters;
        elevationFeet2 = elevationFeet;
        mapName2 = mapName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the featureId
     */
    public int getFeatureId() {
        return featureId;
    }
    /**
     * @param featureId the featureId to set
     */
    public void setFeatureId(int featureId) {
        this.featureId = featureId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the featureName
     */
    public String getFeatureName() {
        return featureName;
    }
    /**
     * @param featureName the featureName to set
     */
    public void setFeatureName(String featureName) {
        this.featureName = featureName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the featureClass
     */
    public String getFeatureClass() {
        return featureClass;
    }
    /**
     * @param featureClass the featureClass to set
     */
    public void setFeatureClass(String featureClass) {
        this.featureClass = featureClass;
    }
    /**
     * @return the stateCode
     */
    public String getStateCode() {
        return stateCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param stateCode the stateCode to set
     */
    public void setStateCode(String stateCode) {
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the stateId
     */
    public int getStateId() {
        return stateId;
    }
    /**
     * @param stateId the stateId to set
     */
    public void setStateId(int stateId) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the countyName
     */
    public String getCountyName() {
        return countyName;
    }
    /**
     * @param countyName the countyName to set
     */
    public void setCountyName(String countyName) {
        this.countyName = countyName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the countyId
     */
    public int getCountyId() {
        return countyId;
    }
    /**
     * @param countyId the countyId to set
     */
    public void setCountyId(int countyId) {
        this.countyId = countyId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the primaryLatitudeDMS
     */
    public String getPrimaryLatitudeDMS() {
        return primaryLatitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @param primaryLatitudeDMS the primaryLatitudeDMS to set
     */
    public void setPrimaryLatitudeDMS(String primaryLatitudeDMS) {
        this.primaryLatitudeDMS = primaryLatitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @return the primaryLongitudeDMS
     */
    public String getPrimaryLongitudeDMS() {
        return primaryLongitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @param primaryLongitudeDMS the primaryLongitudeDMS to set
     */
    public void setPrimaryLongitudeDMS(String primaryLongitudeDMS) {
        this.primaryLongitudeDMS = primaryLongitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @return the primaryLatitudeDecimal
     */
    public double getPrimaryLatitudeDecimal() {
        return primaryLatitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @param primaryLatitudeDecimal the primaryLatitudeDecimal to set
     */
    public void setPrimaryLatitudeDecimal(double primaryLatitudeDecimal) {
        this.primaryLatitudeDecimal = primaryLatitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @return the primaryLongitudeDecimal
     */
    public double getPrimaryLongitudeDecimal() {
        return primaryLongitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @param primaryLongitudeDecimal the primaryLongitudeDecimal to set
     */
    public void setPrimaryLongitudeDecimal(double primaryLongitudeDecimal) {
        this.primaryLongitudeDecimal = primaryLongitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sourceLatitudeDMS
     */
    public String getSourceLatitudeDMS() {
        return sourceLatitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @param sourceLatitudeDMS the sourceLatitudeDMS to set
     */
    public void setSourceLatitudeDMS(String sourceLatitudeDMS) {
        this.sourceLatitudeDMS = sourceLatitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sourceLongitudeDMS
     */
    public String getSourceLongitudeDMS() {
        return sourceLongitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @param sourceLongitudeDMS the sourceLongitudeDMS to set
     */
    public void setSourceLongitudeDMS(String sourceLongitudeDMS) {
        this.sourceLongitudeDMS = sourceLongitudeDMS;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sourceLatitudeDecimal
     */
    public double getSourceLatitudeDecimal() {
        return sourceLatitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @param sourceLatitudeDecimal the sourceLatitudeDecimal to set
     */
    public void setSourceLatitudeDecimal(double sourceLatitudeDecimal) {
        this.sourceLatitudeDecimal = sourceLatitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sourceLongitudeDecimal
     */
    public double getSourceLongitudeDecimal() {
        return sourceLongitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @param sourceLongitudeDecimal the sourceLongitudeDecimal to set
     */
    public void setSourceLongitudeDecimal(double sourceLongitudeDecimal) {
        this.sourceLongitudeDecimal = sourceLongitudeDecimal;
    }
    /**
     * @return the elevationMeters
     */
    public int getElevationMeters() {
        return elevationMeters;
    }
    /**
     * @param elevationMeters the elevationMeters to set
     */
    public void setElevationMeters(int elevationMeters) {
        this.elevationMeters = elevationMeters;
    }
    /**
     * @return the elevationFeet
     */
    public int getElevationFeet() {
        return elevationFeet;
    }
    /**
     * @param elevationFeet the elevationFeet to set
     */
    public void setElevationFeet(int elevationFeet) {
        this.elevationFeet = elevationFeet;
    }
    /**
     * @return the mapName
     */
    public String getMapName() {
        return mapName;
    }
    /**
     * @param mapName the mapName to set
     */
    public void setMapName(String mapName) {
        this.mapName = mapName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the createdDate
     */
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    /**
     * @param createdDate the createdDate to set
     */
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    /**
     * @return the modifiedDate
     */
    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }
    /**
     * @param modifiedDate the modifiedDate to set
     */
    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sortBy
     */
    public SortByType[] getSortBy() {
        return sortBy;
    }
    /**
     * @param sortBy the sortBy to set
     */
    public void setSortBy(SortByType[] sortBy) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(GISData o) {
        /**
         * Make sure to complete this section in such a way that the 
         * type of comparison can easily be changed to factor in the different 
         * types of comparisons you need to make. I've given you a mechanism 
         * in the class to essentially select the comparison type. You can use that 
         * or you could code different methods, call those methods from here 
         * and comment out the methods you won't use. It's up to you.
         */
        return 0;
    }
    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ID: %s\r\nName: %s\r\nClass: %s\r\n");
    }
}
```

I expected the output of each instance of data that I load in. Although this is a huge data set, I simply want to be able to load my data into the program.  Also, if anyone has any suggestions from here on methods I could write to efficiently sort and search the data, I would appreciate it.

(Data set I am using: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blackboard.learn.xythos.prod/5744b9beb8ccb/8090292?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27CA_Features_20190301.txt&response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190525T170332Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21599&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIL7WQYDOOHAZJGWQ%2F20190525%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a0e4ce710ad5f5226b3f60544d897c7bd5cd1da59632e5248655b149ef56f7e3)

Answer (score 0):

## Apache Commons CSV

I let the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library do the chore of reading my text files. (Note: The JavaDoc is [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.6) – their link on home page is broken.)

I start with the `CSVFormat.TDF` format definition, then alter it to expect a VERTICAL BAR (pipe, `|`) rather than a Tab character as the delimiter.

I used an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to name all the fields of your input data. But that is optional, you could have used string names.

Beware of floating point type `double` [trading away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed-of-execution. If you want your numbers kept intact, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

By using objects rather than primitives, we can use a `null` to show where your input is missing data.

I used ternary operator to test for NULL values. A ternary is simply a `if-the-else` statement collapsed into a single line, using syntax of:

```
result = test ? valueToUseIfTestIsTrue : valueToUseIfTestIsFalse ;
```

Example: If the elevation in meters is an empty string, record a NULL. Else, parse the incoming string as an `Integer` object.

```
Integer ELEV_IN_M = record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_M ).isBlank() ? null : Integer.valueOf( record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_M ) );
```

[`String::isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) method is new in Java 11. It tests for an empty string or a string made entirely of whitespace characters. For earlier Java, replace with [`String::isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) in Java 6 and later. Your data seems to have only empty strings, no whitespace, but I did not verify this observation.

Skip the getter/setter methods. Just use `public` member variables until all the other code is working, and until you have a specific reason to layer on accessor methods.

To make quicker work of writing this demo code, I simply copy-pasted your data file’s filed names as-is, all uppercase. I did not bother changing to camel-case per canonical Java.

Here is a complete working example, in one big class with a demo in the `main` method.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Gis
{
    public enum FIELD
    {
        FEATURE_ID, FEATURE_NAME, FEATURE_CLASS, STATE_ALPHA, STATE_NUMERIC, COUNTY_NAME, COUNTY_NUMERIC, PRIMARY_LAT_DMS, PRIM_LONG_DMS, PRIM_LAT_DEC, PRIM_LONG_DEC, SOURCE_LAT_DMS, SOURCE_LONG_DMS, SOURCE_LAT_DEC, SOURCE_LONG_DEC, ELEV_IN_M, ELEV_IN_FT, MAP_NAME, DATE_CREATED, DATE_EDITED
    }

    public String FEATURE_NAME, FEATURE_CLASS, STATE_ALPHA, STATE_NUMERIC, COUNTY_NAME, COUNTY_NUMERIC, PRIMARY_LAT_DMS, PRIM_LONG_DMS, SOURCE_LAT_DMS, SOURCE_LONG_DMS, MAP_NAME;
    public Integer FEATURE_ID, ELEV_IN_M, ELEV_IN_FT;
    public BigDecimal PRIM_LAT_DEC, PRIM_LONG_DEC, SOURCE_LAT_DEC, SOURCE_LONG_DEC;
    public LocalDate DATE_CREATED, DATE_EDITED;

    // Constructor
    public Gis ( Integer FEATURE_ID , String FEATURE_NAME , String FEATURE_CLASS , String STATE_ALPHA , String STATE_NUMERIC , String COUNTY_NAME , String COUNTY_NUMERIC , String PRIMARY_LAT_DMS , String PRIM_LONG_DMS , BigDecimal PRIM_LAT_DEC , BigDecimal PRIM_LONG_DEC , String SOURCE_LAT_DMS , String SOURCE_LONG_DMS , BigDecimal SOURCE_LAT_DEC , BigDecimal SOURCE_LONG_DEC , Integer ELEV_IN_M , Integer ELEV_IN_FT , String MAP_NAME , LocalDate DATE_CREATED , LocalDate DATE_EDITED )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( FEATURE_ID ); // … and so on.
        this.FEATURE_ID = FEATURE_ID;
        this.FEATURE_NAME = FEATURE_NAME;
        this.FEATURE_CLASS = FEATURE_CLASS;
        this.STATE_ALPHA = STATE_ALPHA;
        this.STATE_NUMERIC = STATE_NUMERIC;
        this.COUNTY_NAME = COUNTY_NAME;
        this.COUNTY_NUMERIC = COUNTY_NUMERIC;
        this.PRIMARY_LAT_DMS = PRIMARY_LAT_DMS;
        this.PRIM_LONG_DMS = PRIM_LONG_DMS;
        this.PRIM_LAT_DEC = PRIM_LAT_DEC;
        this.PRIM_LONG_DEC = PRIM_LONG_DEC;
        this.SOURCE_LAT_DMS = SOURCE_LAT_DMS;
        this.SOURCE_LONG_DMS = SOURCE_LONG_DMS;
        this.SOURCE_LAT_DEC = SOURCE_LAT_DEC;
        this.SOURCE_LONG_DEC = SOURCE_LONG_DEC;
        this.ELEV_IN_M = ELEV_IN_M;
        this.ELEV_IN_FT = ELEV_IN_FT;
        this.MAP_NAME = MAP_NAME;
        this.DATE_CREATED = DATE_CREATED;
        this.DATE_EDITED = DATE_EDITED;
    }

    // -------|  Object  |-----------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return new StringJoiner( " | " , Gis.class.getSimpleName() + "{ " , " }" )
                .add( "FEATURE_ID='" + this.FEATURE_ID + "'" )
                .add( "FEATURE_NAME='" + this.FEATURE_NAME + "'" )
                .toString();
    }

    // -------|  Parsing  |----------------------

    static public List < Gis > parseFile ( final String path )
    {
        ArrayList < Gis > list = new ArrayList <>();
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" );
        try
        {
            Reader reader = new FileReader( path );

            CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.TDF.withHeader( Gis.FIELD.class ).withFirstRecordAsHeader().withTrim().withDelimiter( '|' ); // Must pass a `char` to `withDelimiter` not a `String`, so use single-quote not double-quote.
            Iterable < CSVRecord > records = format.parse( reader );
            for ( CSVRecord record : records )
            {
                // FEATURE_ID|FEATURE_NAME|FEATURE_CLASS|STATE_ALPHA|STATE_NUMERIC|COUNTY_NAME|COUNTY_NUMERIC|PRIMARY_LAT_DMS|PRIM_LONG_DMS|PRIM_LAT_DEC|PRIM_LONG_DEC|SOURCE_LAT_DMS|SOURCE_LONG_DMS|SOURCE_LAT_DEC|SOURCE_LONG_DEC|ELEV_IN_M|ELEV_IN_FT|MAP_NAME|DATE_CREATED|DATE_EDITED

                Integer FEATURE_ID = Integer.valueOf( record.get( FIELD.FEATURE_ID ) );
                String FEATURE_NAME = record.get( FIELD.FEATURE_NAME );
                String FEATURE_CLASS = record.get( FIELD.FEATURE_CLASS );
                String STATE_ALPHA = record.get( FIELD.STATE_ALPHA );
                String STATE_NUMERIC = record.get( FIELD.STATE_NUMERIC );
                String COUNTY_NAME = record.get( FIELD.COUNTY_NAME );
                String COUNTY_NUMERIC = record.get( FIELD.COUNTY_NUMERIC );
                String PRIMARY_LAT_DMS = record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LONG_DMS );
                String PRIM_LONG_DMS = record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LONG_DMS );
                BigDecimal PRIM_LAT_DEC = record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LAT_DEC ).isBlank() ? null : new BigDecimal( record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LAT_DEC ) );
                BigDecimal PRIM_LONG_DEC = record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LONG_DEC ).isBlank() ? null : new BigDecimal( record.get( FIELD.PRIM_LONG_DEC ) );
                String SOURCE_LAT_DMS = record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LAT_DMS );
                String SOURCE_LONG_DMS = record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LONG_DMS );
                BigDecimal SOURCE_LAT_DEC = record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LAT_DEC ).isBlank() ? null : new BigDecimal( record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LAT_DEC ) );
                BigDecimal SOURCE_LONG_DEC = record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LONG_DEC ).isBlank() ? null : new BigDecimal( record.get( FIELD.SOURCE_LONG_DEC ) );
                Integer ELEV_IN_M = record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_M ).isBlank() ? null : Integer.valueOf( record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_M ) );
                Integer ELEV_IN_FT = record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_FT ).isBlank() ? null : Integer.valueOf( record.get( FIELD.ELEV_IN_FT ) );
                String MAP_NAME = record.get( FIELD.MAP_NAME );
                LocalDate DATE_CREATED = record.get( FIELD.DATE_CREATED ).isBlank() ? null : LocalDate.parse( record.get( FIELD.DATE_CREATED ) , f );
                LocalDate DATE_EDITED = record.get( FIELD.DATE_EDITED ).isBlank() ? null : LocalDate.parse( record.get( FIELD.DATE_EDITED ) , f );

                Gis gis = new Gis( FEATURE_ID , FEATURE_NAME , FEATURE_CLASS , STATE_ALPHA , STATE_NUMERIC , COUNTY_NAME , COUNTY_NUMERIC , PRIMARY_LAT_DMS , PRIM_LONG_DMS , PRIM_LAT_DEC , PRIM_LONG_DEC , SOURCE_LAT_DMS , SOURCE_LONG_DMS , SOURCE_LAT_DEC , SOURCE_LONG_DEC , ELEV_IN_M , ELEV_IN_FT , MAP_NAME , DATE_CREATED , DATE_EDITED );
                list.add( gis );
            }
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.trimToSize();
        return list;
    }

    // ---------|  Demo (psvm)  |------------------------------------------
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        if ( false ) // Experiment on a small file, a subset of data. If that works, run the huge file.
        {
            String path = "/Users/basilbourque/gis-small.txt";
            List < Gis > list = Gis.parseFile( path );
            System.out.println( "list.size(): " + list.size() );
            System.out.println( "list: " + list );
        } else
        {
            String path = "/Users/basilbourque/gis.txt";
            List < Gis > list = Gis.parseFile( path );
            System.out.println( "list.size(): " + list.size() );
            System.out.println( "list.sublist( 0 , 10 ): " + list.subList( 0 , 10 ) );
            System.out.println( "list.sublist (last 10): " + list.subList( list.size()-10 ,list.size()) );
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> list.size(): 122669
>
> list.sublist( 0 , 10 ): [Gis{ FEATURE_ID='2928' | FEATURE_NAME='Cibola Bridge' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='6185' | FEATURE_NAME='Imperial National Wildlife Refuge' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='8164' | FEATURE_NAME='Mohave Canyon' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='8174' | FEATURE_NAME='Mohave Valley' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='9144' | FEATURE_NAME='Palo Verde Dam' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='9146' | FEATURE_NAME='Palo Verde Intake' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='9227' | FEATURE_NAME='Parker Valley' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='12628' | FEATURE_NAME='Topock Gorge' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='14114' | FEATURE_NAME='Yuma Main Canal' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='22751' | FEATURE_NAME='Cibola National Wildlife Refuge' }]
>
> list.sublist (last 10): [Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833610' | FEATURE_NAME='Marine Corps Recruit Depot Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833611' | FEATURE_NAME='MCAS Miramar Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833612' | FEATURE_NAME='Mount McCoy Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833613' | FEATURE_NAME='NAS North Island Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833614' | FEATURE_NAME='Pala Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833615' | FEATURE_NAME='Pinon Hills Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833616' | FEATURE_NAME='Yermo Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833617' | FEATURE_NAME='Federal Covina Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833618' | FEATURE_NAME='Montalvo Post Office' }, Gis{ FEATURE_ID='27833619' | FEATURE_NAME='Beverly Hills Post Office' }]

In real work, I would move the parsing stuff out to its own class, keeping `Gis` class just for data validation and storage.

Comment: I appreciate the help a ton. One issue I am having when running your code is getting a "The method isBlank() is undefined for the type String" when you parse the file. Any suggestions of how I could relieve this issue?

Comment: @TobyZ  [`String::isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) is new in Java 11. Write your own replacement if you cannot use Java 11 or 12 yet.

Comment: I was also if you could give me some direction in the sense of how to search and sort this data. Any help is greatly appreacited.

Comment: @TobyZ  Searching and sorting a list of objects has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more from existing Questions and Answers. You’ll learn about Comparable and Comparator. And remember to consider NULLs, as much of your data has missing values in various fields.